# How to move xml elements to other position in the layout?

Tags: android

I am developing an Android quiz game.

When a user replies to the first question I open this dialog to show its progress:

[image]

This is the layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <View
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/txtLevel1"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/txtLevel1"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:background="@color/orange" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtLevel3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="5.000" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtLevel2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtLevel3"    
        android:text="2.500"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtLevel1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtLevel2"
        android:text="1.000"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Is there any way to move the `View` element (the orange box) from `txtLevel1` (1.000 points) to `txtLevel2` (2.500 points) maybe with an animation/transition and not statically?

Comment: If you can use jquery on your objects, you could just rearrange the children of the parent object. That wouldn't animate it on it's own, but there should be parameters you can call to make it happen "slowly".

Comment: This might help you: https://github.com/brucetoo/PickView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this to move the orange box from txtLevel1 to txtLevel2:

```
View orangeBox = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.orange_box);
TextView tv = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.txtLevel2);
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams p = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(300, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
p.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_BOTTOM, tv.getId());
p.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_TOP, tv.getId());
orangeBox.setLayoutParams(p);
```

For the animation [this](https://developer.android.com/training/animation/reposition-view) might help you.

Comment: The link helped me! Thank you